# Chime SDK to display all video tile and real time attendee list display using Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, aws-chime-sdk, amazon-chime

*I have heard several times about local tile and remote tile when sharing video meetings. I am trying to display all attendee video tile and facing difficulties making an app from scratch using Vue JS as I'm new to using AWS Chime SDK. I have several questions below.*

`What is the differences between local tile(getAllVideoTiles) and remote tile(getAllRemoteVideoTiles)?`

`How can I show all attendee video tile with their name?`

`How can I add the attendee's name? Where should I pass it? createAttendee or createMeeting API?`

`How can I identify the Host?`

`How can I add in-meeting real-time chat and a list of connected attendees?`

`React library is available. Javascript demo is also huge lines of code that are less helpful to understand for newcomers I think. Are there any chances for Vue JS and Its Demo?`

*Your answer will be much helpful and appreciable for any new developer in near future. Thank you very much.*

Currently, I have an observer which shows myself and one attendee tile only.

```
videoTileDidUpdate: tileState => {
   const audioElement = this.$refs.audioElement;
   const isDefaultVideo = tileState.tileId === 1;
   this.audioVideo.bindAudioElement(audioElement);
   this.audioVideo.bindVideoElement(
       tileState.tileId,
       isDefaultVideo ? this.$refs.defaultVideoElement : this.$refs.attendeeVideoElement
   );
}

<audio ref="audioElement"></audio>
<video ref="defaultVideoElement"></video>
<video ref="attendeeVideoElement"></video>
```

Answer (score 0):

What i understood reading aws-sdk documentation and working through it, I'm sharing my own understanding which may help someone later.

> **What is the differences between local tile(getAllVideoTiles) and remote tile(getAllRemoteVideoTiles)?**
>
> **getAllVideoTiles** get all video tiles including the local one where as
> **getAllRemoteVideoTiles** just return the remote video tiles. You can use
> **getLocalVideoTile** to get the local video tile for the current local
> client.
>
> **How can I show all attendee video tile with their name?**
>
> Since you do not know your attendee name you would need to maintain a
> mapping of the attendee name with an id on your side. You can pass
> that Id to **createAttendee** and then you should be able to retrieve that
> id in **videoTileDidUpdate** event and get the id via **boundExternalUserId**
> property.
>
> **How can I add the attendee's name? Where should I pass it?
> createAttendee or createMeeting API?**
>
> **createAttendee**. See the answer in the previous question.
>
> **How can I identify the Host?**
>
> You can tell if it is a local video in **videoTileDidUpdate** from the
> **tileState** property **localTile**
>
> **How can I add in-meeting real-time chat and a list of connected
> attendees?**
>
> You can refer to this section of the [API Overview](https://github.com/aws/amazon-chime-sdk-js/blob/main/guides/03_API_Overview.md#9-send-and-receive-data-messages-optional) for a simple way to
> send messages in meeting.